# Where can I find a font/vectorial version of the ornament used in TeX.SE?

Tags: support, design

Yes, the one right in the split bar, below the 'E' in 'TeX'...

Comment: jin (the designer of the se sites) is in the chat right now, why don’t you ask him?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The font is [Type Embellishments One](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/letraset/type-embellishments-one/type-ornaments-one/). The ornament below the logo is "8"

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: fixed the link.

Answer (score 8):

I guess, jin will give the answer. In the meanwhile I suggest at least one source for such ornaments.

There's an ornament font called Web-O-Mints which has been created by George Ryan. It contains typographic decorations inspired by historical sources.

- [Web-O-Mints on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/webomints)
- [Homepage and free download](http://www.galapagosdesign.com/original/webomints.htm)
- [Browse examples](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/galapagos/web-o-mints-gd/webomints-gd/)

Sample:

[image]